# Acer Aspire Windows 10 can't find wifi from Huawei E5576

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have an newish (6 months old) acer aspire laptop running windows 10. The wifi on it works just fine except for one device, my portable mobile data wifi router, a Huawei E5576. I can connect to the internet if I plug the router in to charge using a USB cable. Looking at the available connections, this creates an NDIS adapter. But if I unplug it, this laptop alone can't see the wifi network. I've checked through the list of known wifi networks to make sure I haven't blocked or otherwise blacklisted the router's wifi network ESSID. I've connected the laptop to other wifi networks without issue. Other devices in the house (phones, laptops, etc) can all see the wifi network ESSID and connect.

I can't help but think that because this device has been detected as an NDIS device, and presumably installed some drivers, that it's somehow configured the system to not see the wifi, but I might be way off. I've tried searching various forms of "NDIS prevents wifi mobile router" and "can't see wifi network windows 10". The closest thing to my problem wwas [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-cant-find-specific-wi-fi-network/c96678ca-1726-4f50-87ae-c64204204da9)

I don't know what else to do to debug this issue at this point.

Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: Try changing the wifi channel on the router, also try to use an external wifi adapter (if you can get one).

Comment: If you run a different OS (Linux USB Live or s.th. similar) on the Acer, can you see SSID then?

Comment: Thanks @harrymc ! Changing the channel worked. I had to try a few before finding one that detected. If you pop that in as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for the poster was to find a channel for the router on which
his computer had no trouble communicating.

We don't know what exactly was the problem, perhaps some particularity
of the network adapter of his computer, but a good channel was found
after some trial and error.

Comment: For others coming here with this problem, some more information: Channels 11 and 12 were not detectable by the Acer, but were by other devices. I tried channels 5,6,9 and 10, all of which were detectable by the Acer. 10 gave me the best connection, but ymmv